# How does TCP congestion control work

Tags: tcp, ca, segments, cwnd, ss

I dont understand how to calculate the CWND-threshold, the source I'm learning from just says:

> "Initial value of ssthresh may be set to an arbitrarily high value (or
>   size of advertised window)"

Also what is the difference between CWND and segments-to-transmit?

[question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsjY2.png)